# How can I create a new column after 8 items for the data pulled from database in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently this is my code to pull a list of items from database an show under a Menu item:

```
<div class="top">
<ul>
<li class='itemCaption f17o'>&nbsp;</li>
@foreach (var category in Model.CatList)
{
<li>
<a href="/c/@category.Id/@category.Name" class='white'>@category.Name</a>
</li>
}


</ul>

</div>
```

but this displays all the items under one column only.How can i split the list into another column as i reach 8th item in one column?

Comment: currently every data comes one after the other in one column only. i would like this to be split into different column after every 8th element...how can this be done???

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var category in Model.CatList.Select((Value, i => new { i, Value }))
{
    if (category.i % 8 == 0)
    {
        @("</ul></li><li><ul>")
    }
    <li>
        <a href="/c/@category.Value.Id/@category.Value.Name" class='white'>@category.Value.Name</a>
    </li>
}
```

Comment: here it shows error" inconsistent Lambda parameter usage.Parameter types must be all implicit or all explicit" and error2:" the name category does not exist in the current context".why is this? it doesnt say like that before.. so why now?

Comment: what does 'Value ' stand for here?

Comment: is the forloop correct here? @foreach (var category in Model.CatList.Select((Value, int  i => new { i, Value }))

Comment: can you please help on this @Chris Pratt

Comment: `Value` represents what would have originally been returned as `category` in a normal foreach. Instead or just returning the item itself, we're return an anonymous object composed of the iteration index of the loop and the item.